# Spring transaction fail rollback

Tags: spring

I encouter an issue "Spring transaction fail rollback". I have a service class which call 2 DAO to insert data into DB table.

emTrcvLineDAO.create(lineVo) fail to insert into table as the lineVo missing some mandatory fields, but emTrcvHeaderDAO.create(vo) fail rollback and the data still inserted in to DB successfully. I am wondering why it does not rollback as the two DAO are in the same transaction.

Any guys have idea on this? Thanks in advance.

```
 public void saveEmTrcvHeader(List<EmTrcvHeaderVOImpl> voList,  List<ResponseItem> responseItemList) {

        for (EmTrcvHeaderVOImpl vo : voList) {
            emTrcvHeaderDAO.create(vo);
            List<EmTrcvLineVOImpl> lineList = vo.getLineList();
            for (int i = 0; i < lineList.size(); i++) {
                EmTrcvLineVOImpl lineVo = lineList.get(i);
                lineVo.setEmTrcvHeaderId(vo.getEmTrcvHeaderId());
                lineVo.setProjId(null);
                emTrcvLineDAO.create(lineVo);

            }    

        }       

}
```

My transaction configuration:

```
<bean id="txProxyTemplate" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="proxyTargetClass">
        <value>true</value> 
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>             
            <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-java.lang.Exception,-org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException</prop>     
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-java.lang.Exception,-org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My service and dao defined as below:

```
<bean name="emTrcvHeaderService" parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
      <bean class="com.emtrcv.service.EmTrcvHeaderService">
        <property name="emTrcvHeaderDAO">
          <ref bean="emTrcvHeaderDAO"/>
        </property>
         <property name="emTrcvPubSelectIdsDAO">
          <ref bean="emTrcvPubSelectIdsDAO"/>
        </property>
        <property name="emTrcvLineDAO">
          <ref bean="emTrcvLineDAO"/>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <bean name="emTrcvHeaderDAO" class="com.emtrcv.dao.EmTrcvHeaderDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>
  <bean name="emTrcvPubSelectIdsDAO" class="com.emtrcv.dao.EmTrcvPubSelectIdsDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>
   <bean name="emTrcvLineDAO" class="com.emtrcv.dao.EmTrcvLineDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: emTrcvHeaderDAO.create(vo) should be rollack as  emTrcvLineDAO.create(lineVo) fail and throw org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
, but actually emTrcvHeaderDAO.create(vo) does not rollback and the vo data still be inserted into DB.  Why?

Comment: saveEmTrcvHeader() is one of method of emTrcvHeaderService service bean.

Comment: Wow... that is pretty old configuration, I really hope that it isn't something new you are using this on. Without seeing your tx manager configuration and dao implementations and an explanation on which hibernate version you are using, any answer is only a mere guess. You are also failing to explain which database (and optionally table types you are using).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to mention when rollback should take place.
As per doc, 
The concept of rollback rules is important: they enable you to specify which exceptions (and throwables) should cause automatic rollback. You specify this declaratively, in configuration, not in Java code. So, although you can still call setRollbackOnly() on the TransactionStatus object to roll back the current transaction back, most often you can specify a rule that MyApplicationException must always result in rollback.

Please refer http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html for more details

Comment: I already declare the transaction should be rollback if exception throw in "txProxyTemplate" bean definition.  emTrcvLineDAO.create(lineVo) must throw exception as the lineVo data miss some mandatory fields of DB table. however, “emTrcvHeaderDAO.create(vo)" still can save data into DB successfully even   emTrcvLineDAO.create(lineVo)  throws DataIntegrityViolationException.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the root cause. there are two duplicate Spring configuration files both define transaction management rules in the project, it make spring tranasction management not work. After removed one of them, it works.